# We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content,shows on home page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages, home, page-content

We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.
This Error in home page get occures in magento 2.

Comment: How to solve this issue?

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: have you checked var/log files ?

Comment: Enable the developer mode and allow display errors by bootstrap.php and then check the error.

Comment: Please share logs here